# C warning: implicit declaration of function 'htons' & 'ntohs' & 'rand' - are they missing headers?

Tags: c, function

I'm very new to C programming so wondered if anyone could help with these warnings. (I am trying to compile someone else's code, I couldn't code these lol)

```
src/connection.c:79:9: warning: implicit declaration of function 'close' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration
         close(conn->fd);

src/main.c: In function 'main':
src/main.c:37:16: warning: implicit declaration of function 'inet_addr' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     addrs[0] = inet_addr("192.168.252.20"); // Address to bind to


src/server.c: In function 'server_queue_telnet':
src/server.c:93:9: warning: implicit declaration of function 'sleep' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
         sleep(1);

src/telnet_info.c: In function 'telnet_info_parse':
src/telnet_info.c:59:12: warning: implicit declaration of function 'inet_addr' [-Wimplicit-function-decla
     addr = inet_addr(addr_str);


src/telnet_info.c:60:12: warning: implicit declaration of function 'htons' [-Wimplicit-function-declarati
     port = htons(atoi(port_str));

src/server.c: In function 'server_queue_telnet':
src/server.c:93:9: warning: implicit declaration of function 'sleep' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
         sleep(1);

src/util.c:94:9: warning: implicit declaration of function 'close' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
         close(fd);


src/util.c: In function 'util_trim':
src/util.c:161:11: warning: implicit declaration of function 'isspace' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     while(isspace(*str))
```

I managed to fix the above warnings by including the below missing include statements in the appropriate files.

```
include <unistd.h>
include <arpa/inet.h> 
include <ctype.h>
```

However the below warnings still persist and I cannot work out which include statements are missing. When I do **man ntohs** , **man htons** and **man rand** I cannot see any specified libraries that should be included in connection.c and util.c files

```
src/connection.c: In function 'connection_close':
src/connection.c:62:17: warning: implicit declaration of function 'ntohs' [-Wimplicit-function-declaratio
                 ntohs(conn->info.port),

src/connection.c: In function 'connection_consume_arch':
src/connection.c:485:35: warning: implicit declaration of function 'htons' [-Wimplicit-function-declarati
                 ehdr->e_machine = htons(ehdr->e_machine);

src/util.c: In function 'util_socket_and_bind':
src/util.c:77:18: warning: implicit declaration of function 'rand' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     start_addr = rand() % srv->bind_addrs_len;
```

[image]

Comment: Read manual pages, you need some more includes.

Comment: *Some systems require the inclusion of <netinet/in.h> instead of <arpa/inet.h>.* `rand` is in `stdlib`.

Comment: ive just added #include <arpa/inet.h> to connection.c and that has fixed those errors so I just have the 'rand' function warning left to fix

Comment: bingo thanks Eugene thats fixed it !

Comment: @Bat This information is easily located in the man pages right after the "Synopsis". Next time read it more carefully.

Comment: @EugeneSh. As per my post i did check the man page but it doesnt state to use stdlib which is why as a complete novice I asked for help from experts

Comment: @Bat Which system are you using to get the `man` pages?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Debian

Comment: And it is very different from this: https://linux.die.net/man/3/rand ?

Comment: @EugeneSh. yes ive uploaded an image in the description

Comment: this is not the correct man page. Try `man 3 rand`

Comment: ah that is more helpful and why I couldn't find the answer when I looked before. Why do you need to specify the 3 ? ive not come across that before

Comment: Take a look here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3586/what-do-the-numbers-in-a-man-page-mean

Comment: ok thanks I'll take a look and thanks for your help

Comment: don't put images of text here